# How to break from the Catch block after throwing BadRequestException using C#

Tags: c#, .net, break, continue

I have a method which needs to break after the BadRequestException() is thrown.
Currently after BadRequestException() is thrown, frontend shows loading bar buffering infinitely.

 Please find my code below

```
        public FeSite GetSiteBySiteId(string envCode, string siteId)
        {
            try
            {
                envCode.ThrowIfNull();
                siteId.ThrowIfNull();

                var watch = new Stopwatch();
                watch.Start();

                FeSite result = this.ExecuteAndParseWebRequestForEnv<FeSite>(envCode, $"sites/{siteId}", HttpMethod.Get);
                this.LogService.Info($"FeeDataAcccess - GetSitebySiteId - {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");

                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                this.LogService.Error($"GetSiteBySiteId - {e.Message}");
                throw new BadRequestException("Invalid siteId!");
            }
        }
```

Below method calls GetSiteBySiteId() method:

```
        public string GetDevicesSerialNumberBySiteId(string envCode, string siteId)
        {
            var siteSerialNumber = "";
            if (siteId != null)
            {
                var result = this.feeDataAccess.GetSiteBySiteId(envCode, siteId);
                List<string> gatewaySiteSNlist = result.Gateways.Select(x => x.SerialNumber).ToList();
                foreach (var item in gatewaySiteSNlist)
                {
                    var siteSN = item;
                    siteSerialNumber += $";{siteSN};";
                }
            }

            return siteSerialNumber;
        }
```

I have tried this code below :

```
public FeSite GetSiteBySiteId(string envCode, string siteId)
        {
            do
            {
                try
                {
                    envCode.ThrowIfNull();
                    siteId.ThrowIfNull();

                    var watch = new Stopwatch();
                    watch.Start();

                    FeSite result = this.ExecuteAndParseWebRequestForEnv<FeSite>(envCode, $"sites/{siteId}", HttpMethod.Get);
                    this.LogService.Info($"FeeDataAcccess - GetSitebySiteId - {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
                    return result;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    this.LogService.Error($"GetSiteBySiteId - {e.Message}");
                    throw new BadRequestException("Invalid siteId!");
                }
            }
            while (false);
            {
                break;
            }

        }
```

But I get error "No enclosing loop out of which to break or continue" 
How to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: After you throw you exit the scope of the method so the method which calls GetSiteBySiteId has to handle the exceptions. You have to call GetSiteBySiteId in a try catch block as well.

Comment: @Max : I have put my calling method in the question, Can you please explain in detail how to fix this please. How do I break it in my calling method? Break; doesnot work inside try catch block.

Comment: What frontend are you talking about? What progress bar? Post that frontend code. Is this a desktop or a web application? If you throw an exception in a desktop application, the entire application will crash unless you catch the exception. In an MVC app, an exception will result in a 500 response and an error page unless you explicitly catch it. In an SPA, the client code has to actually check whether the response succeeded or failed

Comment: Throwing always exits the current block. Always. If you see an unexpected behavior it's because the rest of your code somehow swallows that exception

Comment: It depends on how your frontend handles the error coming from your backend API

Answer (score 0):

```
 public string GetDevicesSerialNumberBySiteId(string envCode, string siteId)
    {
        var siteSerialNumber = "";
        if (siteId != null)
        {
            try{
            var result = this.feeDataAccess.GetSiteBySiteId(envCode, siteId);
            List<string> gatewaySiteSNlist = result.Gateways.Select(x => x.SerialNumber).ToList();
            foreach (var item in gatewaySiteSNlist)
            {
                var siteSN = item;
                siteSerialNumber += $";{siteSN};";
            }
            }catch{
               //BadRequestException catch and error handling goes here
            }
        }

        return siteSerialNumber;
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9133299/jbatstone : I tried this, Still I have same issue, Buffering infinitely!

Comment: What calls GetDevicesSerialNumberBySiteId()? would probably need to add some condition if siteSerialNumber returns empty

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9133299/jbatstone :I get this error "A break or continue statement was encountered outside of a loop." when i try to add condition and break;

Comment: Post the code that throws that error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9133299/jbatstone : Please check the question, I have posted the changes i tried and got error.

Comment: You modified the wrong function, also adding the do-while loop is pointless. You need to post the function that calls GetDevicesSerialNumberBySiteId() b/c that is where the code is hanging.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251924/discussion-between-philip-and-jbatstone).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9133299/jbatstone : I have posted my code in the chat, please check